# HBase one-to-many relationship with multiple columns

Tags: python-3.x, hbase, hbase-filter

I have been trying to use HBase one-to-many relationship storage. Consider, I have Person table to maintain his/her loans. A person can have multiple loans and I need to store the loan and it's type.

I have gone through the example given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662067/hbase-one-to-many-relationship-storage) and [here](https://grokbase.com/t/hbase/user/08bsdccfmk/capturing-one-to-many-relationship-with-column-famalies), based on that I have kept loan as column family, loans(has unique id) as columns and its type as value. Below is my structure of my Person table

```
ROW     COLUMN+CELL
dinesh  column=loan:DFGHBCN, timestamp=1563443783271, value=home
dinesh  column=loan:FBCPOIBAMN,timestamp=1563443796628, value=personal
dinesh  column=loan:XPABSTWLMN,timestamp=1563443815217,value=personal
```

I want to get the person who has a particular loan from this table. **I wasn't able to do it**. So I changed the structure like below-

```
ROW     COLUMN+CELL
dinesh  column=loan:loan_1, timestamp=1563443783271, value=DFGHBCN
dinesh  column=loan:type_1, timestamp=1563443783271, value=home
dinesh  column=loan:loan_2,timestamp=1563443796628, value=FBCPOIBAMN
dinesh  column=loan:type_2,timestamp=1563443796628, value=personal
dinesh  column=loan:loan_3,timestamp=1563443815217,value=XPABSTWLMN
dinesh  column=loan:type_3,timestamp=1563443815217,value=personal
```

I can able to fetch the person name using ColumnPrefixFilter. I need help on the following

1. How can I achieve one-to-many relationship with multiple columns in HBase and how can I store them?
2. Is there any query to fetch row key by matching the column name? if I am able to achieve can this can I fix the first structure for one-to-many relationship?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am proceeding with first structure as I am able to get the row key by matching the column name(loan id) with the help of ColumnPrefixFilter. Any suggestions/alterations on this please let me know.